# How to manage state asynchronously in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

I am fetching data with

```
 const getAllCountries = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/cities-list`);
      return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return err.response;
    }
  }

 const allCountries = await getAllCountries();
```

Using vanilla JS, I want to add some kind of loading state for slower connections (or in case the api takes longer than normal to respond). I am doing that with

```
 const getAllCountries = async () => {
    try {
      document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = 'Loading'; // Displaying 'Loading' text
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/cities-list`);
      document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = null;
      return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return err.response;
    }
  }

 const allCountries = await getAllCountries();
```

This works fine on slow connections, but on faster connections, the "Loading" text appears for a split second, then disappears, which is expected.

How can I add some kind of delay (like `setTimeout`) such that the loading state only displays after 1 second (as an example)?  If data is returned prior to 1 second, then don't display the loading state.  In other words, users on a fast connection will not see the loading text.

Comment: You would exactly use setTimeout, and if the process happens before the threshold, clearTimeout

Comment: It turns out I was using `setTimeout` in the wrong scope, but I appreciate your answer!

Comment: https://dev.to/chovy/state-management-into-its-own-module-in-vanilla-javascript-58mf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you lift `response` higher in the scope you can access it from within the timeout

```js
const getAllCountries = async () => {

    try {
      let response;

      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!response) {
          document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = 'Loading'; // Displaying 'Loading' text
        }
      }, 1000)
      
      response = await axios.get(`/api/cities-list`);
      document.querySelector('#results').innerHTML = null;
      return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
      return err.response;
    }
  }
```